# Using wild cards in Rewrite Rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've got a site where there are two pages which can handle the products. They have a number either 10 or 21 just before the .html extension.
I want to force the site to always use the 21 extension without losing the page rank on the 10 extension pages that Google has indexed.

The Relative URL looks like this:

```
/site-product/dragons-breath-41658-10.html
/site-product/dragons-breath-41658-21.html
```

I was thinking of using a 301 ReDirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /site-product/(.*)-10.html http://mysite/site-product/$1-21.html
```

I don't know if that would work but for what I want to do, I really need to have a relative destination and thought of using a Rewrite Rule which I'd prefer to use anyway.

Would the following rule work or do I need to adjust the code?

```
RewriteRule ^site-product/(.*)-10.html$    /site-product/$1-21.html [R=301]
```

Comment: That's fine, but add the `L` flag to the rule so it becomes `[R=301,L]`. Also, always use `302` when testing, then switch to `301` when you are confident that everything is peachy.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend changing `.*` to `.+` to avoid capturing `/site-product/-41658-10.html`.

Comment: I took out the L flag becuase I've already got some ReWrite Rules in the .htaccess file for other things and I still want to process them.

Comment: I tired using that Rewrite Rile with your suggestion Mike but it didn't work. I tried it in an htaccess tester and that showed that it should work. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: Perhaps you have placed it underneath another rule that prevents it from running. Please share the contents of your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I pasted the whole .htaccess file into the tester so if it worked there, I don't why it didn't on the live site. The .htaccess file is a bit too long to share here.